# How to type React Hook Form getValue function in reduce method?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

On submit I need to send only `dirtyFields` from React Hook Form to a backend server. To do so I loop through `dirtyFields` with reduce method calling `getValue` function on each field. The problem is that I don't know how to type `field` value in `getValues` without `as any`.

```
  const {
    ...
    getValues,
    formState: { dirtyFields },
  } = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      // ...lots of props including nested props
    },
  });

  const dirtyFieldsData: Partial<FormValues> = Object.keys(dirtyFields).reduce((accum, field) => {
        return {
          ...accum,
          [field]: getValues(field as any),
        };
      }, {});
```

Comment: i guess you can achieve this with `[field]: getValues(field as keyof FormValues)`